# How to shut down (and start up) Moto X without lock button?

Tags: moto-x, shutdown

I have a Moto X and my lock button on the side has broken. Is there any way to shut down the phone even though the button is broken? Will this allow me to start it back up too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ADB: Once you have the Android Debugging Bridge (available with the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) or [packaged separately](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790)) installed on your system and authorized on your device, you can simply run this command from a terminal: `adb reboot -p`
2. Replace the missing button with [a Pressy clone](http://www.gearbest.com/cables-adapter/pp_58618.html) that plugs into your headphone jack. You can then use it with an app like [KeyCut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lennox.keycut&hl=en) to configure what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted, then there are apps that can shut down your device using SU command `reboot -p`, like [Shutdown by Stefan Simroth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubicoo.shutdown), or [Shutdown by Pieter Pareit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.shutdown).

If you want to reboot instead, try [Quick Boot (Reboot)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot) or [Quick Reboot (Root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=phongit.quickreboot). Again, you need the device to be rooted.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question also. Would this allow me to turn it back on?

Comment: Updated the answer for reboot options.